# What if 1st law of motion and 2nd law of thermodynamics contradict?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, entropy

Assume a large flat surface with a pile of books on it somewhere. Assume this system to be **isolated** and **gravity** to be present there. Also assume there to be a **flow of time**.

As now you have successfully imagined the situation, you can see all the energy of the system (*Gravitational potential energy*) is concentrated at one place.
According to the **2nd law of thermodynamics** ,*energy should dissipate in the system evenly*, so the system shouldn't be like this forever. For entropy has to increase with time, and only way for that to happen is, if the books start scattering on the surface somewhat evenly, for that way energy of the system will disperse.

But this happening, inturn violates another vital law of nature, ie **1st law of motion**. For any body to change it's state there must be some external unbalanced force applied on it. I can't see anyway for that force to exist, as the system is isolated. In simple words I mean, system should abide by both the laws. But what's happening here is, only one law seems to prevail. Which one, we don't know.

*Now, I'm drawing my conclusions*__

-> Does it mean that *Newton's 1st law of motion* and *2nd law of thermodynamics* contradict each other for an isolated system? And if they do contradict each other, then which law prevails in above situation?

-> Or does it mean, in order to keep these laws from contradicting each other, nature will manifest a **cause** for a force to exist, so it could knock down the pile of books.

And I don't expect nature to manifest sucha cause outta thin air. I mean, like filling the system with enough complexity of properties, such that these complexities cause the surface *(in our example)* to crack and let the gravity do its work. Like atoms and molecules doing their mysterious thing, like coming up with some never before seen chemical reaction or something like that. I mean, nature will make it impossible for a system to exist without enough complexity, in order to keep the fundamental laws of nature from contradicting each other.

Now here's the twist in the argument. I intentionally missed a vital part of 2nd law of thermodynamics, to make a conclusion that, I could disprove later, to try to prove something else outta it. Here it is__

**2nd law of thermodynamics actually states that, "*The entropy of an isolated system should always increase or be the same, but never should it decrease"**.

Now that's an important point right there. If the entropy of our system can remain the same over time, the energy concentrations can remain the same. So, the pile of books doesn't have to fell to the ground without any force. This way both the laws are followed by the system.
Now what it means is, my argument was wrong, so were my conclusions and most particularly the second one. Now when the second conclusion  is wrong, so is the requisition that a system must have enough complexity or any complexity at all.

So, here's my question.
**Can a system have no complexity at all?**

**Can a system be actually fundamental?**

Like something fundamental at the smallest scales of length of the universe. Like strings from string theory, or something even smaller than strings. Something which are actually the building blocks of our reality.

Comment: Think about what the books are made from.

Comment: Why should it matter?

Comment: Books are made of molecules. These vibrate and form time to time the structure did the bonds will change and that will lead to an increase in entropy. I don’t see why you need an external force for this to happen. It seems to me that your gedenken experiment is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

> For entropy has to increase with time,

Actually, the "with time" part is not included in the the 2nd law of thermodynamics. That law says that entropy, *if* it changes, will increase overall. But it doesn't say that it necessarily *must* increase. It describes the behaviour, so to say, but not the cause.

Still, we do generally except the entropy to change over time, but that is due to the many events that constantly take place all the time in our world - many processes, reactions, and interactions. In your idealised scenario with no such events, there is no reason to except any entropy to change. The book stack can theoretically stay stationary forever without violating the 2nd law of thermodynamics.

With that being said, don't forget that you are focusing narrowly on the macroscale (requiring the book stack to rearrange) in your description. What is to say that the changes and forces you are asking for aren't happening internally at the microscale (decomposition e.g.)?

> Can a system have no complexity at all? Can a system be actually fundamental?

This requires some clarification - it should possibly be a new question. It depends on your definition of complexity and fundamental systems.

Comment: The thing about time came from that one article that I read online. It talked about the entropy defining the arrow of time. That it is the only law of nature that takes the arrow of time in consideration. And with that I want to add that, well keeping the pile of books at rest is what I wanted. What I meant by fundamental was, something that has no further roots. Like a beginning. What I'm asking is, is there an origin to all the complexity?

Comment: @TanfeexUlhaqq It is indeed interesting how the 2nd law of thermodynamics, which governs the direction of processes and reactions, also defines the arrow of time. That is because time basically only is measureble when things are changing - time is a term "invented" to describe general change. The 2nd law of thermodynamics describes the direction of this change, so the direction of time. But if nothing happens - if no events take place - then you won't be able to measure time. And you won't ...

Comment: ... see any entropy change. On the other hand, if you look at the system with you own wristwatch, then do measure time and the entropy of your watch does increase over time - but the entropy of the closed system you are observing doesn't necessarily change.

Comment: @TanfeexUlhaqq "an origin to all the complexity" is again not a very precise definition. What exactly is it you want to find the origin of? What is complexity in your definition? I am not clear about what a system with no roots would mean

Comment: well, I really seem to lacking what it needs to explain my thoughts. One last try. Earlier it was understood that atoms were the smallest and most basic creations of all. Their arrangements is what made everything around us. But then even basic particles were discovered and they were considered fundamental. This trend went on, from subatomic particles to bosons and etc. My question is, is there is a stop to this? Is there something that breaks this trend? Something that can't be broken down even further.

Comment: Well according to my argument, (if it's true) , as 1st law of motion and 2nd law of thermodynamics don't contradict each other, a system with no complexity must be possible. By complexity here I mean, if something is complex we can break it into parts, like atoms can be broken down as a combination of subatomic particles.

Comment: @TanfeexUlhaqq Alright, I understand what you mean by complexity. I do not follow why those two laws both being true must imply that a non-complex system is possible, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120275/discussion-between-tanfeexulhaqq-and-steeven).